# Attempting to call js from Blazor Server App

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm attempting to call a very simple js function from a razor script but it keeps throwing me the same error and I can't simply understand what's wrong.

This function is contained on a js script under wwwroot/js/jsScript.js

```
function showAlert(message) { 
    alert(message); 
}
```

And I'm attempting to call it from MyPage.razor

```
@{
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @onclick="ShowAlertWindow">Show Alert Window</button>
}

@code {
    protected async Task ShowAlertWindow()
    {
        //IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("console.log", "ShowAlertWindow");
        await IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert", "JS function called from .NET");
    }
}
```

As soon as I run my app it then crashes:

[image: error]

Browser's console errors:

[image: console error 1]

[image: console error 2]

Same errors in text:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of jsScript.js:1 404 ()



blazor.server.js:19 [2021-02-09T00:29:40.323Z] Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'showAlert' in 'window'.
Error: Could not find 'showAlert' in 'window'.
    at https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:30944
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at p (https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:30904)
    at https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31614
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:31587)
    at https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20052
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at e.invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:20022)
    at e.processIncomingData (https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:18006)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at FIS.IO.Pages.Index.ShowAlertWindow() in C:\Users\tfaon\source\repos\FIS.IO\FIS.IO\Pages\Index.razor:line 27
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

**Any ideas as to why this is happening? I must be doing something really wrong.**

Comment: Did you register the script file containing showAlert function?

Comment: Yes, on the Pages/_Host.cshtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that IJSRuntime can not find the javascript function `showAlert`, you could foget to add the reference in **Pages/_Host.cshtml**.

```
<script src="~/js/jsScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did, yes. Something else has to be missing, I just don't understand what it could be.

Comment: After adding this, there is any other error shows?

Comment: No, only that it could not load the resource and that the function could not be found in window.

Comment: Actually this worked, but for some reason VS was bugged and it seems like it only assumed these changes after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was simply adding a new function to an existing .js file. Then I too received the error that the function couldn't be found.

The only solution that worked was to clear the browser cache and reload (in my case CTRL-F5).

Answer (score 0):

with me it worked when I set the function outside: $(document).ready();